# Pyinstaller throwing out AssertionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

So, I had been working on this game i created using sockets and pygame, and now I wish to send it to another computer. I do not want to send the files as is, but instead an executable that I can run without downloading and installing anything new.

I tried using pyinstaller, but it threw an `AssertionError`

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/osx.py", line 195, in fix_exe_for_code_signing
    assert len(sign_sec) == 0, "Executable contains code signature!"
AssertionError: Executable contains code signature!
```

I am on MacOS Sierra, version `10.12.6`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was a problem with python3.8, the pyinstaller commands work just fine for python3.7 and python3.9